# break In emacs type multiple commands on the same line

Tags: c#, break

In C, it is possible to type multiple commands on the same line. For example, consider the code below:

```
float x = 27.0; float y = 27.0; /* break here */ float sum = x + y;
```

Based on what know about gdb and debugging programs, explain how you would set a breakpoint to stop the program before it executes the last statement in the third line (where `/* break here */` is located), but after it executes the second statement (`float y = 27.0`).

Comment: `C` or `C#`? In either language you can type multiple *statements* on the same line, separated by terminating semicolons. I know nothing of gdb. You should consider making the tag and the text agree on language. You should also consider adding a `gdb` tag (I'm assuming there is one) and making your question title reflect what you seem to be asking (about gdb). You'll have a better chance of getting a useful answer. Oh, and what does emacs have to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible, move the cursor to the command and press F9

[image: break point]